# how to extract set of lines using separator from file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching, text-extraction

I have below 3 queries in a single flat file. i want to split 3 queries separately into 3 files. Each query is seperated by";"(semi colon). Please suggest how can i do this?

**input file:** query.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table1;

select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;

select * from 
DBNAME.table3
WHERE date<= current_date-30;
```

**output** should be

file1: query1.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table1;
```

file2: query2.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;
```

file3: query3.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table3
WHERE date<= current_date-30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can make it:

```
awk -v RS="" '{print > "query"(++i)".sql"}' file
```

With `-v RS=""` we define each record as a paragraph. Then it is a matter or printing them to `queryNUMBER.sql`. To do that, we use the `++i` that increments every single time.

See created files:

```
$ cat query1.sql 
select * from 
DBNAME.table1;

$ cat query2.sql 
select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;

$ cat query3.sql 
select * from 
DBNAME.table3
WHERE date<= current_date-30;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i used -v RS=";" instead of -v RS="" as  i wanted the paragraph to be separated with ";"

Comment: Yes i got what i needed.

Comment: how do i modify the above command if i wish to extract only 2nd query. i.e. 
select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;

Comment: @Abdul well you can for example do `awk -v RS="" 'NR==2{print > "query2.sql"}' file`. This will extract the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these sed commands to get each set of lines, and send them to the right file.  The first sed command gets lines 1 and 2, and sends them to query1.sql.  The second sed command gets lines 4 to 6, and sends them to query2.sql.  The third sed command gets lines 8 to 10, and sends them to query3.sql.

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -n '1,2p' query.sql > query1.sql
sed -n '4,6p' query.sql > query2.sql
sed -n '8,10p' query.sql > query3.sql
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.